# getting difficulty in generating the Dyanmic checkbox from the database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datamapper, codeigniter-datamapper

I am using Codeigniter and Datamapper for DB Query. My controller is as follows

```
function fetch_interested_in()
{
    $in = new Interested_in();      
    $in -> get();
    $interested_in = array();
    foreach($in -> all as $data)
    {
        $interested_in[$data -> in_id] = $data -> in_title;
    }
    return $interested_in;
}
```

And my view file is as follows

```
    <?php foreach($interested_in as $in)

                        echo form_checkbox('in_in[]', $in -> in_id); 

    ?>
```

There are 3 rows in my table called Interested_in. 2 columns are there and names are in_id and in_title. When I run the code I get the following error in page at 3 places one after another.

**

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Trying to get
>   property of non-object Filename: views/poverview.php Line Number: 137

**

Please let me know where am I going wrong. I'll really be very thankful to you. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php foreach($interested_in as $in)

                    echo form_checkbox('in_in[]', $in); 

?>
```

Is enough.

Your title/id is "saved" in `$in` and not `$in->id_id`.

But in your case I guess you want:

```
<?php foreach(array_keys($interested_in) as $id):

      echo '<label>'.$interested_in[$id].'</label>';
      echo form_checkbox('in_in[]', $id); 

      endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: Oh wow... Its working... Thanks a lot for the quick reply... One more small doubt is there. I want to display the title too... What do I've to write...? column name is in_title... Thanks in advance...

Comment: exactly. I could not keep my question in correct way. Sorry for that. You are right. But above code displays lebel 3 times and checkbox only for one time.

Comment: I want to display the checkbox adjacent to label. Thanks again for the quick reply.

Comment: you are just awesome. I must not be this much lazy. You are fantastic. Its working like magic... Thanks thanks Thanks thanks Thanks thanks a lot...